# javascript can't separate view from data

Tags: javascript, callback, dao

i don't understand something with javascript callback. I'd like to do something like a DAO in Java where I manipulate my data then call the DAO object in my controller. But in javascript I have something like this :

DAO

```
function DAO() {
    this.getData = function(arg1, arg2, callbackSuccess, callbackError) {
        var data = null;

        // do something to get data. If ok then call callbackSuccess
        callbackSuccess(data);
    }

    var callbackSuccess = function(data) {
        // HERE I HAVE THE DATA. HOW TO RETURN IT TO <DATA> ?
    }

    var callbackError = function(data) {
        // ERROR
    }
}
```

Somewhere else where i need to fetch data ...

```
var dao = new DAO();
var <DATA> = dao.getData(var1, var2, callbackSuccess, callbackError);
```

I can probably put the callback in my controller and send them to the getData method but that's seem strange to me...

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the difference between synchronous and asynchronous code.

In synchronous code, every statement you execute is evaluated and its result returned to you. No other statement is evaluated until you finish evaluating the current statement. As such, statements are evaluated always in order.

```
var a = syncStatement1();
var b = syncStatement2();
console.log("finished!!!");
```

In the code above `syncStatement2()` would never be evaluated before `syncStatement1()`. And the log "finished!!!" will only be printed when all the code within the two preceding functions has been completed.

In asynchronous code, though, the order of execution is different. When you ask an asynchronous statement to be evaluated, the execution engine simply schedule it for evaluation at some point later and continues executing your program.

```
var a = asyncStatement1();
var b = asyncStatement2();
console.log("finished???");
```

In this second example above, the execution engine will not wait for every statement function to evaluate before executing the next statement. By the time you reach the logging line saying "finished???" you cannot be sured that the previous functions have finished executing.

The executing engine has simply schedule them for execution, and at some point it will execute them and "return" whatever they return, but that did not happen when you initially invoked them.

This has several implications, the first is that you cannot ask for a result of an asynchronous function like `a = asyncFunc()` because what should be the value of `a` if the function has not even run yet?. Most likely undefined, since there is no result available yet. However, depending on how you are creating the asynchronous function, you may get back a promise object, that you can also use to cancel the asynchronous action, or to ask, later on, if there is a result available.

The second implication is that, since the code will execute later on, within a context you have no control whatsoever, the only way to know what happened is by asking the function itself to notify you of the results, and that is why you are forced to register callbacks with your asynchronous functions, like:

```
function asyncFunc(args, success, error) {
   //do something here
   if(success) success(data);
}
```

There is no way to go around this and pretend the code is actually running in synchronous mode. You are forced to change the way you are thinking.

As I said above, depending on the framework that you are using, you may get a promise from your asynchronous function and change the things a bit to look slightly better as in:

```
var promise = asynchFunc(args);
promise.success(function(data) {
   //do something with data when successful in async.
});

promise.error(function(error){
  //handle the error that happened in async.
});
console.log("Most likely not finished yet!!!");
```

But this is still asynchronous execution and by the time you reach the log, you most likely have not yet handled any callback.

Some third party libraries like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) can make your life slightly simpler when dealing with this type of code, in case you want to give them some consideration.

Finally, to address your question, you cannot do this

```
var dao = new DAO();
var <DATA> = dao.getData(var1, var2, callbackSuccess, callbackError);
```

But you could do this:

```
var <DATA> = null;
function onSuccess(data){
  //act on your data and update controller
  <DATA> = data;
}

function onError(error){
  //handle error
}

dao.getData(var1, var2, onSuccess, onError);
```